# How to use Core Data w/ seed database + public CloudKit database to update + private db for individual user data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit

I've used CloudKit before, but only to sync private user data across devices.

For a new app, what I would like to do is prepopulate a database with seed data to be used with Core Data on the device and then sync information from a public CloudKit database to ensure that the local one is up-to-date (my understanding is that public databases work a bit differently).

But at the same time, I would like to allow users to create their own objects that are private to them, as well as favorite both objects they create and included ones, and to store that in a private CloudKit database.

It seems like this should be possible using multiple stores in Core Data and multiple instances of NSPersistentCloudKitContainer, but the setup seems a lot more complicated due to being unable to create relationships between entities in different stores.

Has anyone tried a setup like this before and would be willing to offer some insight?

Comment: Hi, please be sure to post relevant code, what you've tried and what your errors are.

Comment: @Joshua There is no code or errors at this point. I'm asking for advice about creating a particular configuration.

Comment: @JEMG3, I'm looking to build the same thing, my problem is importing an initial seed for new users as the CKMirroring is slow and will take more than 2 minutes for all my records to get mirrors locally for the user. How did you go around this problem?